# MySQL: How to enable load data local on both, client and server sides

Tags: mysql, database, import

I tried to upload a .txt file into MySQL Workbench, but I have the following issue:

> Error Code: 3948 Loading Local data is disable; this must be enable on both the client and server sides

Answer (score 2):

Workbench uses a MySQL feature called [LOAD DATA LOCAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) for this .txt file import operation. Because that feature exposes [some security problems](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html) in the server, the operator of the server needs to enable that feature, by running the MySQL server software (`mysqld`, it's called) with a specific system variable called [`local_infile`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile).  Your error message means that flag is not enabled.

You can try enabling it at runtime before you do your upload operation. Try this SQL statement.

```
SET @@GLOBAL.local_infile = 1;
```

If that doesn't work you need to ask the person who runs your server to enable it.